# Android RelativeLayout - show items side by side when space but on separate lines when insufficient space?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm laying out an app which presents the results of a search in a ListView. I've defined each item to have a custom layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSearchResultTitle"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subtitle" 
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:gravity="bottom|left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This looks great when subtitle and date are of appropriate length to fit on a single line, however it looks awful if the subtitle consumes most of the line and forces date to take a very thin width and so wrap vertically.

What I'd like to do is have them appear side-by-side when there's space but on separate lines if there isn't. I've tried fiddling with the various layout_* attributes and the gravity to no avail and the question isn't very Google-able (at least, I can't think of the right words to search for). Can anyone point me towards the combination of layout rules that I need to achieve this? Or perhaps a different container if one would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code below will do what you want but I can't see a way to do this only in the xml layout.
Basically I have added a textChangedListener to two different TextViews that have the two different layout options I believe you are looking for, both inside their own relative layout with the date displaying textview.  When the subtitle is set the first of these is used to hold the text, if it requires more than a single line the second TextView is used and in either case the other has its visibility option set to GONE.
In my example I use a seperate thread to change the subtitle, hopefully this doesn't confuse things too much.

The layout xml is as follows:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSearchResultTitle"
    android:background="#FF009999"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:text="@string/my_title" />
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/resizingTextContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:background="#FF000000" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/subtitle1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#FF00FF00" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/subtitle2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#FF00FF00" />    
</RelativeLayout>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/startTestBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/resizingTextContainer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Click To Begin"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And the main activity code with the textview switching logic:

```
    package com.example.code.examples.changelayoutwithtextlength;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextWatcher textChangeDisplayCheck = new TextWatcher(){
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        displayLatestSubtitle(s);           
    }           
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView DateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
    DateTextView.setText("29th April 2013");

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startTestBtn);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            v.setEnabled(false);
            Thread thread = new testSubtitleThread();
            thread.start();
        }           
    });

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subtitle1);   
    tv.addTextChangedListener(textChangeDisplayCheck);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subtitle2);
    tv2.addTextChangedListener(textChangeDisplayCheck);
}

private void displayLatestSubtitle(CharSequence newSubtitle)
{
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subtitle1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subtitle2);

    tv.removeTextChangedListener(textChangeDisplayCheck);
    tv2.removeTextChangedListener(textChangeDisplayCheck);

    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tv2.setText("");
    tv.setText(newSubtitle);

    if(tv.getLineCount() > 1)
    {
        tv.setText("");
        tv2.setText(newSubtitle);
        tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    tv.addTextChangedListener(textChangeDisplayCheck);
    tv2.addTextChangedListener(textChangeDisplayCheck);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class testSubtitleThread extends Thread
{
    String[] subtitles = new String[] { "a short one", "a really long winded subtitle that will take over more than the allowed space", "tiny",
            "Really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long.",
            ".....", "text just to long to fit on my device"};

    private android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler()
    {
        @Override             
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) 
        {                 
            if(msg.what < subtitles.length)
            {
                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subtitle1);
                tv.setText(subtitles[msg.what]);
            }
            else
            {
                Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startTestBtn);
                b.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void run()
    {   
        for(int i = 0; i <= subtitles.length; i++)
        {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(i);    
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                           
        }
    }   
}
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Seems to be there as a solution, so I'll accept. Sadly it seems to be a bit of a faff just to get the effect I was going for, so I've instead set `android:maxLines="1"` on the date TextView and set the subtitle to be `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"` and removed the date's `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subtitle"`. This means that the date is always on a single line on the right and padding keeps the subtitle suitable contained in its spot on the left (possibly consuming multiple lines). Thank you anyway for your solution to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, I would define two Views per item (subtitle and date), one in the same line and one in the line below.
Then I would check the length of those 2 fields (or their sum) and I would write this piece of code:

```
 if (length > MAX_LENGTH_OF_LINE) > {
        findViewById(R.id.subtitle_line_below).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.subtitle_same_line).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.subtitle_line_below).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.subtitle_same_line).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```